# piezoelectric sensor sensitivity

Tags: sensor, piezo, board, development

I am experimenting with this guy - http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-Piezo_Vibration_Sensor/ and it seems to be quite insensitive. It won't respond to table knocks when I knock it with the piezo bender having some heavy weights (hundreds of grams) on top. Same deal with no weights. I have even tried to tap it directly and no answer. Also adjusted the on-board potentiometer.

The only way this piezo strip gives an answer is by fast bending + fast releasing. I am reading the output with `delay(2)` to make sure I am not missing anything. From what I have read I should be able to pick fine vibrations with it by just adding a minuscule weight. Maybe mine is broken ?

Comment: What specifically (and numerically) did the unit promise to deliver performance wise in its data sheet? What does "fine vibrations" mean in terms of pressure variations and across what spectrum? In other words, are your expectations based on something as tangible as written numbers or words?

Comment: Busted! I thought I was going to reproduce the results from this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygFHyzrkwVk - and I now realize the piezo element from the video differs from mine.